# открыть файл в int python

Tags: python, бот

Пытаюсь открыть открыть файл и прочитать его содержимое как число: `[file = int(open("fallen.txt", "r"))]`.

Нужно для `TelegramApi`.

```py
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types

#button
ramuveDel = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
button_function = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,resize_keyboard = True)
IDcheck = types.KeyboardButton('/ID')
button_function.add(IDcheck)

token = '[_token_]'
client = telebot.TeleBot(token)

lol  = open("faq.txt", "w")

@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_qtext (message):
    #chat
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!', reply_markup                        = button_function)

#######################################################################################
@client.message_handler(commands=['starts'])
def qhandle_text (message):
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi')
    @client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def handle_text(message):
        
        file = int(open("fallen.txt", "r"))
        files = [map(float, line.split("\t")) for line in file]

        txta = message.text

        suma = file + int(txta)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, suma)
#######################################################################################

client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Comment: Вы совершенно не понимаете, что делаете, да?

Comment: `with open('fallen.txt') as f: num = int(f.read())`.

Comment: токен уберите из кода

Comment: `f = open('fallen.txt'); num = int(f.read()); f.close()`

Comment: с python особо не имел дел, и 3 день искал как сделать что бы работало. Спасибо вам!

Токен не действителен :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно нормально открыть файл и прочитать его:

```
with open("fallen.txt", "r") as file:
    num = int(file.read())
```